# What permissions are required to create Azure subscriptions and tenants?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-rbac

According [to this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#classic-subscription-administrator-roles) the Classic Account Admin can create Subscriptions.

- Is there anyone else who can create subscriptions as well? Can he delegate this administrative task through AAD roles?
- In the new RBAC approach do we still have a 'Classic' Account Admin?

In my organization's Tenant, I have the user AAD role. I tried to create another Tenant expecting it to fail due to permissions, but it succeeded.

- What kind of permissions are required to create a new Tenant? (since a simple 'user' was able to create it)

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any restrictions around that. Why should users not be allowed to create tenants?

Comment: creating a new tenant is like creating a new account, why wont you be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Account Administrator, Service Administrator, and Co-Administrator are
>   the three classic subscription administrator roles in Azure.

In the doc, it just explains there are there type classic subscription administrator roles, it means you could create the three type admin roles in the classic subscription.

> In the new RBAC approach do we still have a 'Classic' Account Admin?

It depends on the subscription you have. If you have the classic subscription, you could create the classic type admins.

> What kind of permissions are required to create a new Tenant? (since a
>   simple 'user' was able to create it)

No permissions are required to create a new Tenant. Every user could create a new free tenant.

Comment: there is not classic subscription